# Using a gyroscope to get to space

Tags: momentum, inertial-frames, inertia, space-travel, gyroscopes

Theoretically, if you could get an inertial mass or gyroscope spinning fast enough while on the earth' s surface, then as the earth turned would it continue to travel in a straight line and therefore launch itself into space? If so, how fast would it have to spin?

(I do realize this is entirely impractical using any of our current technology or that of the foreseeable future.)

Comment: No, a gyroscope can't lift itself off the ground any more than you can pull yourself up by your own bootstraps. The rotation doesn't change that.

Comment: The *translational* motion of the complete gyroscope is still influenced by gravity whether it is spinning or not. It is no more likely to "launch itself into space" than a rock resting on the earth's surface.

Answer (score 1):

It would continue to be oriented in a straight line -- its orientation would not change as the earth rotates (like the orientation of most objects would).  However, it is still subject to the forces of gravity acting upon its center.  These would still pull the gyro to the ground.

Gyroscopes resist being deflected.  If you put one side of the gyro up on a pedestal, the pull of gravity would not be able to cause the gyro to torque down (instead it torques to the right), but it's still being held up by the pedestal.

When in doubt, I defer to VSauce.  His [explanation of gryos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHGKIzCcVa0) is most excelent, and addresses some of the effects you are thinking of.

Comment: I am actually not really concerned about what direction it would be oriented in but in how fast it would have to be spinning to escape the Earth's gravity well. Since as it spins it's inertial mass increases but it's gravitational mass stays the same it should overcome gravity and leave the earth at some point.

Comment: That's why I point at orientation.  Spinning does not increase its inertial mass.  It increases it's moment of inertia, but that is only used for rotations not linear movements such as the effect of gravity about its center of mass.  Gravity will just pull the gyro to the ground like it wasn't spinning at all.

Comment: Interesting! I will have to go back and research gyroscopes more. Thanks!

Comment: @MathMan If you have stumbled across some of Prof Eric Laithwaite's work on gyroscopes, ignore it. It's somewhere between "extremely misleading" and "total nonsense". Prof Laithwaite was an excellent *electrical* engineer (for example he did some early work on maglev trains) but for some reason he seems to have thought he was the first person to "discover" gyroscopes, and completely screwed up when trying to explain them - for example, he convinced himself that they didn't obey the laws of Newtonian mechanics!